# Proving $dim(img(g\circ f)) \leq dim(im(f))$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to prove: $dim(img(g\circ f)) \leq dim(im(f))$. $g$ and $f$ are linear maps.

The map $f$ first maps the input $x$ into $im(f)$. $g$ take $im(f)$ into $im(g)$. Thus, this last map is $g_{im(f)}$, $g$ restricted to image of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any linear map $L$, we must(*) have $dim(img(L))\le dim(dom(L))$, i.e. the image has dimension no larger than the domain.

Hence $dim(img(g_{im(f)}))\le dim(dom(g_{im(f)}))=dim(im(f))$.

(*) This follows from the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), i.e. $$dim(im(L))+dim(ker(L))=dim(dom(L))$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
By the rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of the image of a linear map is lessthan or equal to the dimension of its source.